# How to open a large csv file in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I collected data from social media platforms and stored it in a csv file, I have around 1.8 million comments in this file  and I am trying to open it using pandas. I used engine as python while opening, the file size is 122 MB and it has code mixed comments with emojis, but I am getting an error.

```
ParserError: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead
```

So i tried with engine='c' but now got a different error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: @ Dishin H Goyani yes it worked forreading the file  but when i tried to convert it to list i am getting error  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'tolist'                            i tried  df = dd.read_csv(), df["column"].tolist()

Comment: Did you get same error?

Comment: I am not able to access the content now, i am able to read the file to data frame

Comment: Is there anything in the dataframe or is it showing null?

Comment: I changed the engine to "python" from "c", i tried df.head(5), i got the first five comments, but how can i convert to a list i tried df["column"].tolist(), i am getting Sereis has no attribute tolist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222014/discussion-between-learner-and-dishin-h-goyani).